getOrderCollectionFactory with only orders containing specify Attribute Set - Magento2.4
We would like to create our own getOrderCollectionFactory based on Magento\Sales\Order\History, with only orders containing specify Attribute Set.
How can we extend the addFieldToFilter part?
public function getOrders()
{
    if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$this->orders) {
        $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
        )->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        );
    }
    return $this->orders;
}


try this way to get order collection
$attributesetId = '18';// Replace with attribute id you want to search
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
             $orderdata = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
             $orderdata->getSelect()->join(array('order_item' => 'sales_order_item'),'main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id')
    ->join(array('catalog_product_entity' => 'catalog_product_entity'),'order_item.product_id= catalog_product_entity.entity_id');
             $orderdata->addFieldToFilter('catalog_product_entity.attribute_set_id', $attributesetId);
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($orderdata->getdata());
             echo "</pre>";


Sadly that does not work; Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.order_id.entity_id' in 'on clause', query was: SELECT main_table.*, order_item.*, catalog_product_entity.* FROM sales_orderASmain_table INNER JOINsales_order_itemASorder_itemON main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id  INNER JOINcatalog_product_entity ON order_item.product_id= catalog_product_entity.order_id.entity_id WHERE (catalog_product_entity.attribute_set_id = '247')

@JGeer i updated the query can you try now

Thanks! But I need it in my public function getOrders() function, because I only want to load it from a specific customer

Second problem is that the entity_id from the getOrders() function is changed, so the real entity_id from the order is incorrect

@JGeer
Hey,
Use
$orderCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => $attributeSetId]); 
    

To fetch orders containing products with a specific attribute set in Magento 2.4.
Thank You!
